# How to rotate a text in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to rotate a text for a graph y-axis label, but trying to use transform from the documentation isn't working for me. Could it also be because I'm using the text within an SVG element?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRt9b.png)